# Python Remove Duplicate Dict

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to remove duplicates from a dict list. I don't have to test the entire object contents because the "name" value in a given object is enough to identify duplication (i.e., duplicate name = duplicate object). My current attempt is this;

```
newResultArray = []

    for i in range(0, len(resultArray)):
        for j in range(0, len(resultArray)):
            if(i != j):
                keyI = resultArray[i]['name']
                keyJ = resultArray[j]['name']
                if(keyI != keyJ):
                    newResultArray.append(resultArray[i])
```

, which is wildly incorrect. Grateful for any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: This is, indeed, wildly incorrect. Can you provide a definition for `resultArray`? I'm assuming it is an array of dictionaries. If `name` is unique, you should just use a dictionary to store your inner dictionaries, with `name` being the key. Then you won't even have the issue of duplicates, and you can remove from the list in O(1) time.

Comment: @h0r53 resultArray is an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `name` is unique, you should just use a dictionary to store your inner dictionaries, with `name` being the key. Then you won't even have the issue of duplicates, and you can remove from the list in O(1) time.

Since I don't have access to the code that populates `resultArray`, I'll simply show how you can convert it into a dictionary in linear time. Although the best option would be to use a dictionary instead of `resultArray` in the first place, if possible.

```
new_dictionary = {}

for item in resultArray:
    new_dictionary[item['name']] = item
```

If you must have a list in the end, then you can convert back into a dictionary as such:

```
new_list = [v for k,v in new_dictionary.items()]
```

Comment: thanks. Actually, the ultimate issue I am facing (not in the original scope of my question) is that I ultimately am concatinating this with another list called "result". So where I am doing finalList = result + new_list. WHen doing this I get an error TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict_values") to list

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy I updated the solution so that `new_list` is truly a list. So you should have no issues with concatenation using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since "name" provides uniqueness... and assuming "name" is a hashable object, you can build an intermediate dictionary keyed by "name". Any like-named dicts will simply overwrite their predecessor in the dict, giving you a list of unique dictionaries.

```
tmpDict = {result["name"]:result for result in resultArray}
newArray = list(tmpDict.values())
del tmpDict
```

You could shrink that down to

```
newArray = list({result["name"]:result for result in resultArray}.values())
```

which may be a bit obscure.

Comment: thanks. This works perfectly with the exception that I need the collection as a list rather than a dictionary. Is there an alternate way or else a quick conversion to a list?

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy - goot point! I forgot that in python 3.x, values isn't a list. But it can be fed to `list()` to make one.